# Cuba and other countries

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I got a project running on Google Cloud Platform but is not accesible from Cuba. I know that there are some restrictions but since this is a non-profit project and also a non-profit organization I wonder if there is a chance to open our site to the entire world?

The organization is CONABIO (Commission for Knowledge and Use of Biodiversity of Mexico).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately GCP/Google and most cloud providers that are based in the United States have to follow federal rules that limit services to countries with embargoes. They won't be able to remove the restriction for you, you'll likely need to find another host based outside of the United States.

> Google restricts access to some of its business services in certain countries or regions, such as Crimea, Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria. 
>   ...
>   Certain Google services might be available in these countries or regions for personal use, but not for business or education use.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [FridayPush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10240790/fridaypush), Google restricts access to some of its business service in certain countries or regions, such as Crimea, Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria. Google does apply this restriction as it follows US trade regulations and thus relaxing any embargo is not dependent on Google itself. You can check at this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en).

These are the same countries restricted by the GCP. Here is a [list](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Pages/Programs.aspx) of countries affected by the US trade regulations. The sanctions are different from country to country.